# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, swing, noclassdeffounderror

I made my own Password Manager with java. I store the data with MongoDB and my IDE is VSCode. I can run the project without any problems in VSC. I made a .bat file to start the program from my Desktop. But when i use this shortcut, i get the following Error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients
```

i use:

```bash
java -cp target/passwordManager-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.mongodb.logic.Main
```

as my start command in the .bat file.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>passwordManager</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>passwordManager</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
            <fork>true</fork>
            <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\javac</executable>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <filters>
                  <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                      <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                  </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                  <transformer
                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <manifestEntries>
                      <Main-Class>org.mongodb.logic.Main</Main-Class>
                      <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                    </manifestEntries>
                  </transformer>
                </transformers>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>org.mongodb.logic.Main</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

also here is a Minimal:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getMail("test"));
    }

private static String getMail(String nameOfWebsite) {
        String email = null;

        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(uri)) {
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("passwordManager");
            MongoCollection<Document> collPW = db.getCollection("passwords");

            Bson filter = Filters.eq("nameOfWebsite", nameOfWebsite);
            MongoCursor<Document> curserPW = collPW.find(filter).iterator();

            try {
                while (curserPW.hasNext()) {
                    email = (String) curserPW.next().get("email");
                }
            } finally {
                curserPW.close();
            }
        }
        return email;
    }
```

Comment: Unless that snapshot jar is made a 'fat jar' with Shade or similar, you are going to have to include the jars it depends on in the classpath

Comment: i made it a 'fat jar' but that doesn't seem to help. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It didn't work. You should probably post pom.xml formatted as code

Comment: At this point, it would be a good thing to consider providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just one source file required where your error still occurs

Comment: i added the minimal. When running this code with VSC it works fine, but again with using the CMD command i get the `NoClassDefError`

Comment: You're not quite there yet. You need to do the following: 1. back up your original org.mongodb.logic.Main 2. Make the code you posted compile and run as org.mongodb.logic.Main and 3. Post the code that does that in place of the single method you just posted

Comment: i added the main method for the minimal and it exactly like in my application. Same result

Comment: The code won't compile: a. `uri` is undefined and b. there are no imports

Comment: If you want to keep `uri` 'quiet', pass it into `getMail` from a command line argument to`main`

Comment: `uri` is defined with the correct `String` and the imports are also in the file, i just didnt implement them here

Comment: You were meant to. See my answer edit with running code

Comment: [Here you go](https://technojeeves.com/tech/mongoq.zip) Unzip it then `mvn package` Run it as shown in the edit to my answer with *your* url and it *should* run for you

Answer (score 0):

Your shade config looks off. This is one that works for me. You can start with this and add your nodes until it breaks:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Main-Class>${main.class}</Main-Class>
                            <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Your code running with my parameter suggestion (error as I don't have mongodb so the server url is invalid):

```
goose@t410:/tmp/java-quick-start-master$ java -jar target/java-quick-start-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar mongodb://localhost
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused}}]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.getDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.getConnectedClusterDescription(MongoClientDelegate.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate.createClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.getClientSession(MongoClientDelegate.java:291)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$DelegateOperationExecutor.execute(MongoClientDelegate.java:183)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.execute(MongoIterableImpl.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoIterableImpl.iterator(MongoIterableImpl.java:90)
    at org.mongodb.logic.Main.getMail(Main.java:25)
    at org.mongodb.logic.Main.main(Main.java:14)
goose@t410:/tmp/java-quick-start-master$
```

Comment: Still doesnt work for some reason. But i noticed something while executing the program in VSC. When i use a method that conntects to MongoDB the console shows:

`Aug 11, 2023 2:31:55 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.Loggers shouldUseSLF4J
WARNING: SLF4J not found on the classpath.  Logging is disabled for the 'org.mongodb.driver' component`

Comment: That's something entirely different of course. It's a *warning* (not an error) telling you that your driver will not debug itself without slf4j as a dependency. So you're saying you're still getting the *same error* as before with the new Shade config (to which you need to correctly specify the main class to run as an executable jar)?

Comment: Yeah, still the same Error. I specified `org.mongodb.logic.Main`, which is my Main class with my main method. But im not sure what you mean with the "to run as an executable jar" bit. Do I have to use an other file?

Comment: I mean if you want to run it as `java -jar target/passwordManager-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: I edited the pom to my exact code. Maybe you can find a mistake there. It is still not working. Im starting to believe that i have to manually start the program, which is fine i guess. Either way you helped me a lot so far

Comment: OK but you should do that in conjunction with making `Main` standalone so we can try it